# Sum of Cases on Account

Tags: case, account, roll-up-summary

I'm looking for easy way to create two Case related fields on the Account object:

- One should be a number, a sum of all Cases related to all the Contacts link to an Account
- The other should be an average of "Customer Satisfaction score" for the cases where we received such feedback.

How should I proceed with this? It seems like when using a formula field on an Account, I can't do a sum of all Cases etc.

Thanks a lot.
/Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew Fawcett's [Declarative Rollup Summary tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) will probably let you do what you want without needing to use Apex code.

It lets you create the rolloup summary fields without needing Master Detail relationships between the objects, e.g. Case and Account. You can install it as either a managed or unmanaged package.

The latest release notes are at Andrew's blog [here](https://andyinthecloud.com/2016/06/19/declarative-rollup-tool-summer-release/) and there is extensive documentation there and at [github](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/wiki).